# Can 11,000 be written １.１万?

Tags: numbers

I have seen 11,000 written as １万１０００, but not as １.１万 (the way one may write '3.5 millions'). Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent in arabic numbers of ３．２千](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/59293/what-is-the-equivalent-in-arabic-numbers-of-%ef%bc%93-%ef%bc%92%e5%8d%83)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, we do sometimes utilize a large number as a unit for brevity, and of course it is customary to use powers of 10<sup>4</sup> (万, 億, 兆...) in Japanese, instead of those of 10<sup>3</sup> (thousand, million, billion...).

The decimal representation could be seen everywhere I think the English counterpart would be used except when the discrepancy of order matters; for example, beneath a viral tweet usually shown:

[image]

which is in the Japanese UI:

[image]

where you can see a decimal is followed by 万 (ten thousand).

As an aside, in some fiscal or statistical documents they use 10<sup>3</sup> scale (such as 123.4千円 or 56.7百万人), in order to align the order with the international convention. But this is quite unusual practice outside the field.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can but it's somewhat uncommon in general usage. However, it can be used often in some scenarios such as when one is renting a property. Here are some examples I found:

> 人口1.1万（2010）(From the [デジタル大辞泉 entry for the city of 夕張](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/224565/meaning/m0u/))
>
> 仕事後の寄り道　月1.1万円 (From a [Nikkei article](https://www.nikkei.com/article/DGKKZO42774450S9A320C1PPE000/))
>
> 家賃5.5万円以下物件特集ページ (From a [rental page](http://www.maruya-y.jp/rent/)) [image: 5.5万円]

However, I don't think this construction is used a lot in general. You can surmise this from the [number](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11175074266) [of](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10120656725) [questions](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1034168510) [on](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11152640961) [Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14137054659) [about](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1227084197) [similar](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12163782142) [constructions](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14128638639).

Answer (score 3):

If you put 1.1万 into google you will see how it can be used. It is possible to use it but from all of the examples I saw on the first 5 pages of google it seems to mostly be used in a statistic rather than normal messages or replies. So if you are putting it in a statistic I would say it is ok, other wise 1万1千 seems to be the go to or just 11,000.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I assume 11万 is a typo for something here...?

Comment: 11万 is a very different number. Should be 1万1千 or other equivalents.

Comment: Thanks yushi for catching that. You are right, it should be 1万1千. I will edit that now.